# Why do I need to have a default constructor in QVector<MyClass>?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qvector

I am having trouble compiling the following:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>
#include <vector>

class item
{
    int var;
public:
    //Without default constructor this program will not compile
    //item(){}

    item(int value)
    {
        var = value;
    }
    int getVar()
    {
        return var;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //This code will not compile
    QVector<item> y;
    y.append(item(1));
    qDebug() << y[0].getVar();

    //std::vector however will work despite an absence of a default contructor
    std::vector<item> z;
    z.push_back(item(1));
    qDebug() << z.at(0).getVar();

    return 0;
}
```

To be precise the append line will not compile.

Why item has to have a default contructor in this case?

Comment: Probably to allow `QVector::resize` to be able to default construct `item`s.

Comment: @user4581301 But the same thing should be applicable for `std::vector` also. Right?

Comment: @KunalPuri good point. I need to turn off C++11 and check something.

Comment: `vector` only complains if you use `resize` or similar that force default construction. `QVector` may have more going on behind the scenes. I'm going to have to leave this one to folks with a much higher level of familiarity with QT.

Comment: [What is the reason of QVector's requirement for default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380402/what-is-the-reason-of-qvectors-requirement-for-default-constructor) may be of use.

Comment: [No matching call to default constructor, when using QVector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181249/no-matching-call-to-default-constructor-when-using-qvector) seems to suggest that this is no longer a hard requirement in future versions of QT.

Comment: @KunalPuri downvotes / upvotes can and should be anonymous so the request for justification is currently considered: *it's no longer needed* since it does not contribute anything, for more information check [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: @eyllanesc I agree with your point. But I have a doubt. Whenever anyone downvotes an answer, stackoverflow recommends to leave a comment. Then why that doesn't apply for questions?

Comment: @KunalPuri Good question, maybe in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) have an answer, some time ago I do not give downvotes to answers. but I think it's a suggestion, not an obligation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No matching call to default constructor, when using QVector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181249/no-matching-call-to-default-constructor-when-using-qvector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `std::vector` works differently lies in the fact that in vector, *raw uninitialized memory* is allocated and then calls copy constructor to do the copy whenever required. This process doesn't require **calling default constructor** for `resize()`. That's why there is no dependency as such on default constructor.

For more info, See [AnT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187690/ant)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376989/why-dont-stdvectors-elements-need-a-default-constructor).

`QVector` requires type to be default constructible because of the way the internal function `realloc()` is implemented.

Source: [Understanding the Qt containers](https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/)